# python bsddb doesnt flush when removing entries

Tags: python, synchronization, flush, bsddb

I got a python BSDDB database. Obviously, it's stored on the hard drive. When I remove some entries, the file on the drive does not get any smaller (consequently - it grows quite fast...)

```
utDelList   = []
urlsDelList = []
for ut in iter(self.urls2task):

    tmp = string.split(ut, ":")
    uid = tmp[1]
    url = cPickle.loads(self.urls[int(uid)])
    urlsDelList.append(uid)             
    utDelList.append(ut)                
    del self.urlsDepth[uid]
    del self.urlsStatus[uid]
    del url

for ut in utDelList:
    del self.urls2task[ut]

for uid in urlsDelList:
    del self.urls[int(uid)]

(...)
#synchronize all files
self.sync()
```

My last hope was to force the flush in a savage way - by closing and opening the files again

```
#close all files & start them again, eg
self.tasks.close()
self.urls2task.close()
self.tasks = bsddb.rnopen(filepath)
self.urls2task = bsddb.hashopen
```

the crucial element here is the self.tasks entry; it grows the fastest and biggest of all files. Does pickling-save change anyhow the way of removing it? And, once again - why do the files still keep the entries after removing them?
Id be grateful 4any suggestions (first post here :))

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the [db.compact()](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/4.8.4/db.html#db-methods) method ?

According to the documentation :

> **compact(start=None, stop=None, flags=0, compact_fillpercent=0, compact_pages=0, compact_timeout=0)**
>
> Compacts Btree and Recno access
>   method databases, and optionally returns unused Btree, Hash or Recno
>   database pages to the underlying filesystem.
>
> The method returns the number of pages returned to the filesystem.

Sounds like it should reduce size of the database on disk

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no way to get space back from a btree database by itself.
The best you can do is db_dump all data in a text file and create a new db with db_load of that file.

Answer (score 0):

you should compact your base as described into http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/db.html#db-methods